# Is it possible to do $lookup with an internal array based on a condition within a mongo document

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, lookup

I have list of clientSubscription, each clientSubscriptions has an array of subscription.The activeSubNo indicates which subscription is live and upcomingSubNo indicates the upcoming/next subscription.

```
{    
    "clientNo" : 3,  
    "activeSubNo" : 2,  
    "upcomingSubNo" : 3,
    "subscriptions" : [ 
        {
            "subNo" : 1, "Type" : "FREE", "startDate" : ISODate("2021-09-02"),"endDate" : ISODate("2021-11-02")
        }, 
        {
            "subNo" : 2, "Type" : "PAID", "startDate" : ISODate("2021-12-02"), "endDate" : ISODate("2022-02-04")
        }
        , 
        {
            "subNo" : 3, "Type" : "PAID", "startDate" : ISODate("2022-02-05"), "endDate" : ISODate("2022-05-04")
        } ]
}

{    
    "clientNo" : 5,  
    "activeSubNo" : 2,  
    "upcomingSubNo" : 0,
    "subscriptions" : [ 
        {
            "subNo" : 1, "Type" : "FREE", "startDate" : ISODate("2021-09-02"),"endDate" : ISODate("2021-11-02")
        }, 
        {
            "subNo" : 2, "Type" : "PAID", "startDate" : ISODate("2021-12-02"), "endDate" : ISODate("2022-02-03")
        }]
}
{    
    "clientNo" : 6,  
    "activeSubNo" : 1,  
    "upcomingSubNo" : 0,
    "subscriptions" : [ 
        {
            "subNo" : 1, "Type" : "FREE", "startDate" : ISODate("2022-01-01"),"endDate" : ISODate("2022-02-28")
        }
        ]
}
```

I need to build a view which is sorted based on the earliest expiring clientSubscription. So the comparison of endDate needs to be done only between activeSubscription's date between each of the records. if upcomingSubNo value is 0, then view should indicate that no new subscription has been bought.

View

```
Client Active-SubNo Type StartDate EndDate       Upcoming-SubNo Type StartDate EndDate
5       2          PAID   2021-12-02  2022-02-03           -
3       2          PAID   2021-12-02  2022-02-04        3      PAID 2022-02-05 2022-05-04
6       1          FREE   2022-01-01  2022-02-28           -
```

Is it possible to do this with a single collection like this and an aggregate query?
Or do I have to break this into 2 collections(taking subscriptions as a separate collection), so that I can do the lookup ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      startDate: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$subscriptions.startDate", { $subtract: [ "$activeSubNo", 1 ] } ] },
      endDate: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$subscriptions.endDate", { $subtract: [ "$activeSubNo", 1 ] } ] },
      Type: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$subscriptions.Type", { $subtract: [ "$activeSubNo", 1 ] } ] },
      subscriptions: {
        $cond: {
          if: { $eq: [ "$upcomingSubNo", 0 ] },
          then: "$$REMOVE",
          else: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$subscriptions", { $subtract: [ "$upcomingSubNo", 1 ] } ] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VikOGKF4w5D)

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I have been able to modify your query and was able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The documents seem to be self referencing from the array field that is contained within itself i.e. `subscriptions`. I am assuming the `subNo` is guaranteed to be unique & auto-incremented ensuring no 2 `subscriptions` element conflict on same `subNo`. I believe the intuitive thing here would be to still equality-check than doing the `$subtract` arithematic to land on the right index. I suggest you do:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
 {
   "$addFields": {
     "activeSubscription": {
       "$first": {
         "$filter": {
           "input": "$subscriptions",
           "as": "s",
           "cond": {
             $eq: [
               "$$s.subNo",
               "$activeSubNo"
             ]
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
 },
])
```

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/s30-8WLq5Ve)